# How to calculate Time Interval

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I need to get the time Interval in such a way that exclude the time interval of offline mode. Let me explain you in a time line.

Example:

```
A: |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
B:     |----|                    |-------------|
C:                                         |--------------|
D: |===|    |====================|                        |====================|
```

---

```
`A` is the time line.
`B` is a offline time of `B`
`C` is a offline time of `C` notice that they are overlapping with `B`
`D` is the time to be billed.
```

All I have the Timestamps. I ran out of all the solutions. I wonder if anyone can guide me if there is a way out. Or can suggest me if there is other way around.

Thanks.

Comment: what output do you need?

Comment: The Interval like `16hr 15min`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sort the timestamps temporally;
2. maintain the "total time offline" accumulator and an integer counter;
3. go through the list of events one by one;
4. if the counter is currently zero, add the difference of current timestamp and previous timestamp to the accumulator;
5. if the current event is "went offline", increment counter; otherwise decrement the counter.

This should give you the appropriate time in the accumulator.